# How would I put the data from a field as a result in a CASE statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

If I had this statement:

```
select distinct
(CASE WHEN substr(field_1,1,5) != field_2 THEN 'unassigned' ELSE field_3 END) as Place
```

...so field 3 is input into the 'Place' when field_1 is equal to field_2 and if they aren't equal, then 'unassigned' is put in. The query works when I don't include field_3 and instead include NULL, but I would like to find the most efficient way to do this.

here is my full statement I'm getting issues with. Ran fine until I included the CASE statements... More specifically, I'm getting an "unexpected end to SQL statement" error.

```
select distinct 
       (CASE WHEN substr(tc.cust_pstal_cd, 1, 5) != terr.sls_pstal_cd THEN 'unassigned' ELSE to_char(terr.sls_rgn_nm) END) as Region,
       (CASE WHEN substr(tc.cust_pstal_cd, 1, 5) != terr.sls_pstal_cd THEN 'unassigned' ELSE to_char(terr.sls_dist_nm) END) as District,
       (CASE WHEN substr(tc.cust_pstal_cd, 1, 5) != terr.sls_pstal_cd THEN 'unassigned' ELSE to_char(terr.sls_terr_nm) END) as Territory,
       tc.cust_nm, tc.cust_addr, tc.cust_city, tc.cust_st, tc.cust_pstal_cd,
       (select itm_grp_trd_desc from another_placeholder i where tc.itm_cd = i.itm_cd) as a_thing_1,
       (select i2.itm_ndc_11 from another_placeholder i2 where tc.itm_cd = i2.itm_cd) as a_thing_2,
       to_char(tc.billing_date, 'yyyy-mm') as Month,
       (select cmb.contr_no from placeholder_table cmb where 
       (tc.sales_amt / tc.qty) as Price,
       tc.qty, tc.sales_amt
  from placeholder_table_2 tc,
       placeholder_table_3 dd,
       terr_placeholder terr
 where tc.whlslr_cd IN (select wv.whlslr_cd from placeholder_table_4 wv, placeholder_table_5 tc
                         where wv.whlslr_cd = tc2.whlslr_cd
                           and wv.some_desc = 'Placeholder')
```

Comment: It might be not working because you are not giving any condition so it is not knowing which field_3 value to put in the else condition as it is a column i suppose.

Comment: Is it not working when u r including _field_3_?

Comment: Please define "not working"

Comment: just edited the main post with the full statement I have and the error I've been getting since I added the CASE statements.

Comment: where is the table alias `terr` coming from?

Comment: just added it, forgot to include it in the example on the post.

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE WHEN substr(field_1,1,5) <> field_2
THEN 'unassigned' ELSE to_char(field_3) END as Place
```

The reason your statement doesn't work is because `field_3` is numeric.

To resolve this, `field_3` has been cast as a character string.

Edit: You have many issues going on with your query. Comments included in line. You should correct them before executing. The `case` part of your question should work now.

```
select distinct 
CASE WHEN substr(tc.cust_pstal_cd, 1, 5) != terr.sls_pstal_cd THEN 'unassigned' ELSE to_char(terr.sls_rgn_nm) END as Region,
CASE WHEN substr(tc.cust_pstal_cd, 1, 5) != terr.sls_pstal_cd THEN 'unassigned' ELSE to_char(terr.sls_dist_nm) END as District,
CASE WHEN substr(tc.cust_pstal_cd, 1, 5) != terr.sls_pstal_cd THEN 'unassigned' ELSE to_char(terr.sls_terr_nm) END as Territory,
tc.cust_nm, tc.cust_addr, tc.cust_city, tc.cust_st, tc.cust_pstal_cd,
(select itm_grp_trd_desc from another_placeholder i where tc.itm_cd = i.itm_cd) as a_thing_1,
(select i2.itm_ndc_11 from another_placeholder i2 where tc.itm_cd = i2.itm_cd) as a_thing_2,
to_char(tc.billing_date, 'yyyy-mm') as Month,
--(select cmb.contr_no from placeholder_table cmb where 
--complete this statement by including this table in the join clause
(tc.sales_amt / tc.qty) as Price,
tc.qty, tc.sales_amt
from placeholder_table_2 tc 
JOIN placeholder_table_3 dd ON --add a join condition
JOIN terr_placeholder terr ON --add a join condition
where tc.whlslr_cd IN 
(select wv.whlslr_cd from placeholder_table_4 wv, placeholder_table_5 tc
where wv.whlslr_cd = tc2.whlslr_cd
and wv.some_desc = 'Placeholder')
```

Comment: I'm getting an "unexpected end of SQL statement"

Comment: Please post the full statement you are using.

Comment: (CASE WHEN substr(tc.cust_pstal_cd, 1, 5) != terr.sls_pstal_cd THEN 'unassigned' ELSE to_char(terr.sls_rgn_nm) END)

Comment: i meant the full statement including the `select`

Comment: added it to the main post, couldn't fit it in a comment